# how can i change my JAVA card life cycle state to OP_READY?

Tags: smartcard, lifecycle, javacard, apdu, globalplatform

I found the below script in the Oracle ([This lint](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3563244)) and run it via `GPShell` on my java card and now I can't run `gpj -list` in `GPJ`!

My questions:

1- What is this code for? changing Card Domain Manager status from OP_READY to Secured?

2- Why I can't find anywhere `80F0800708A000000003000000` And `80F0800F08A000000003000000` APDUs that used in script?! I searched `GP Specification 2.2` and `ISO 7814-4` for an APDU with `F0` in `CLA` section! But I found nothing!

3- Is the operation of the below script reversible by another script?

The Script :

```
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect

select -AID A0000000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -kek_key 

404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 80F0800708A000000003000000
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 80F0800F08A000000003000000
card_disconnect
release_context
```

And this is it's output in Console :

```
C:\Users\ghasemi\Desktop\GPShell-1.4.4>gpshell lcchange.txt
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect
select -AID a00000
Command --> 00A4040003A00000
Wrapped command --> 00A4040003A00000
Response <-- 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF9000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4
f -enc_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -kek_key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4
d4e4f
Command --> 80CA006600
Wrapped command --> 80CA006600
Response <-- 664C734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864
886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B06092B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012
A026E01029000
Command --> 805000000823CE2F4C2B6C689B00
Wrapped command --> 805000000823CE2F4C2B6C689B00
Response <-- 0000116001007F8B0AF9020201D1C94E4F787D75DD54805A7488BCF79000
Command --> 84820100100BCCFE8818D2DFC6E5B48EA4B6892457
Wrapped command --> 84820100100BCCFE8818D2DFC6E5B48EA4B6892457
Response <-- 9000
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 80F0800708A000000003000000
Command --> 80F0800708A000000003000000
Wrapped command --> 84F0800710A0000000030000007AA29B3A708E6E75
Response <-- 9000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
send_apdu -sc 1 -APDU 80F0800F08A000000003000000
Command --> 80F0800F08A000000003000000
Wrapped command --> 84F0800F10A0000000030000004FCFC15FD7EBDE9A
Response <-- 9000
send_APDU() returns 0x80209000 (9000: Success. No error.)
card_disconnect
release_context
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is this code for?**

```
80 F0 8007 08 A000000003000000
```

This is a SET STATUS (INS = `0xF0`) command to set the issuer security domain (P1 = `0x80`) to INITIALIZED state (P2 = `0x07`).

```
80 F0 800F 08 A000000003000000
```

This is a SET STATUS (INS = `0xF0`) command to set the issuer security domain (P1 = `0x80`) to SECURED state (P2 = `0x0F`).

**Why I can't find those APDUs used in the script anywhere?**

Most likely because you did not properly read the Global Platform Card specification (e.g. see section 11.10 in GP Card Specification 2.2.1). Btw. searching for 'F0' (the second byte of a C-APDU is INS not CLA) would certainly have helped.

**Is the operation of the script reversible?**

Again, actually reading the specification would have helped. There is a nice state transition diagram in Figure 5-1 that clearly indicates that transitions to INITIALIZED, SECURED and TERMINATED states are irreversible (so does the text in section 5.1.1).

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mr. Roland. :) , I'll read the GP Specification again more accurate tonight!! :)